# Python shutil rmtree doesn't remove directory itself

Tags: python, shutil, python-os

I used [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) . Whenever I run `shutil.rmtree()` to remove a directory, the folder itself is still there, leading to a pileup of folders that I don't need every time I run the program. I have even tried running `os.rmdir()` to get rid of the empty folder, but that doesn't work for some reason either. No errors are thrown, the folder just is simply not deleted. I have the code as follows:

```py
shutil.rmtree(appDir, ignore_errors=False)
os.rmdir(appDir, dir_fd=None)
```

Everything inside `appDir` is deleted, except for `appDir` itself, which I also need to be deleted.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Show us the value of `appDir` --  is it an absolute path, or a relative path?

Comment: i did os.chdir(appDir), meaning it couldn't delete the dir it was currently in, i fixed it by changing the dir it was in

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
os.chdir(appDir)
```

meaning it couldn't delete the dir it was currently, I was able to fix it by doing

```
os.chdir(dir)
```